# KDevelop: transform selected text?

Tags: kdevelop

I was wondering whether there was a function in KDevelop similar to the one that we used to have in Quanta (miss you, Quanta, btw).

I would like to set a keyboard shortcut, and apply a text transformation upon hitting it. Example:

I select `my text to be translated`, and I get back: `<?=_('my text to be translated'?>`
As you can see, this saves me a lot of awkward keystrokes...

I only found this feature in PHPStorm (where it is called "Live Templates"). I defined it like this: `<?=t('$SELECTION$')?>` and I can call it by hitting CTRL+ALT+J, and select it from the dropdown that appears.

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers" is a bullet point on the [on-topic list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of the [help]. An IDE is such a tool. This question is on topic here.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I just re-read the on-topic list :)

Comment: No problem. Common misconception - for some reason people think that library, IDE and build questions don't belong here when they do.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that using a snippet with the following text: `<?=_('%{selection}'?>`

And you can bind a Shortcut to a snippet.

However my tests showed that this doesn't work correctly - there seems to be a bug somewhere.

As alternative you can write a script that does insert the text. See the [documentation](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/applications/kate/dev-scripting.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was not aware of the snippets plugin before. It is promising, but you are right, looks like there is a bug in it because I too get unexpected results... Looks I am out of luck :\